# How to disable a preloader for some specific browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `preloader script` for my website which displays an image for a few seconds before loading the full site.

The problem is, for some browsers, the preloader is working for infinite amount of time. Actual content is not shown at all.

**Question:** Is there a way to disable the preloader functionality for those browsers?

The preloader script is as follows:

```
<script>
setTimeout(function(){  
$(".se-pre-con").fadeOut("slow");;
}, 4000);
</script>
```

Comment: shouldn't you make the preloader disappear once all content is loaded? Something like 53% of people leave if a page takes longer than 3 seconds to load

Comment: can you please tell me how to add that functionality please? @Luca

Comment: you could use something like modernizr if it relies on certain features

Comment: Not really without seeing how your page loads stuff in... In the end you just need to call `$(".se-pre-con").fadeOut("slow");` once everything has been loaded in, e.g. after all AJAX calls are `done`

Comment: It would probably better to fix the underlying issue rather than hide it.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is, for some browsers, the preloader is working for infinite amount of time.

The way your script works now is that if the page hasn't loaded by the time the timeout runs, nothing will happen because the element to fade out isn't yet there.

Since you're using jQuery, you can use something like this to determine when the DOM content is ready:

```
$(function () {
  // Now... do stuff
});
```